# Writing unsigned int to binary file

Tags: c++

My first time working with binary files and I'm having clumps of hair in my hands.  Anyway, I have the following defined:

```
unsigned int cols, rows;
```

Those variables can be anywhere from 1 to about 500.  When I get to writing them to a binary file, I'm doing this:

```
    myFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&cols), sizeof(cols));
    myFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&rows), sizeof(rows));
```

When I go back to read the file, on `cols = 300`,  I get this as result:

```
44
1
0
0
```

Can someone please explain to me why I'm getting that result?  I can't say that there's something wrong, as I honestly think it's me who don't understand things.  What I'd LIKE to do is store the value, as is, in the file so that when I read it back, I get that as well.  And maybe I do, I just don't know it.

I'd like some explanation of how this is working and how do I get the data I put in read back.

Comment: How is `myFile` declared?

Comment: You should consider using Boost Serialization. It will make it very easy to archive anything into a binary file or ascii or whatever you want: [Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html)

Comment: @jogojapan: ofstream myFile;

Comment: Can you post the code of reading from the file?

Comment: 1 * 256 + 44 * 1 is 300. If you read it back you'll get the original value.

Comment: You can simply do `myFile << cols << rows` then when reading it from istream, just read it in same order as you wrote it, via `>>` operator

Comment: @PeteBecker: could you explain how you come to those values and those calculations?

Comment: Each byte in the file has 8 bits, so can represent values from 0 to 255. It's written in little-endian order, with the low byte first. So, starting at the other end, treat the numbers as digits in base 256. The value is 0 * 256^3 + 0 * 256^2 + 1 * 256^1 + 44 * 256^0 (where ^ means exponentiation, not xor).

Answer (score 2):

You have not (yet) shown how you unmarshal the data nor how you printed this text that you've cited.  `44` `01` `00` `00` looks like the bytewise decimal representation of each of the little-endian bytes of the the data you've written (decimal "300").

If you read the data back like so, it should give you the effect you want (presuming that you're okay with the limitation that the computer which writes this file is the same endianness as the one which reads it back):

```
unsigned int colsReadFromFile = 0;
myOtherFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&colsReadFromFile), sizeof(colsReadFromFile));
if (!myOtherFile)
{
    std::cerr << "Oh noes!" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the data is being read back on a completely different platform, an 8-bit Arduino.  So not only do I not have all of tools from c++ to read the data back in, I have to content with it's 8-bit limitation as well.  So while I understand that the `44` `01` `00` and `00` are correct, I have to figure out how to translate that on the Arduino side.

Comment: @KirAsh4, I advocate the suggestion from others to consider a serialization library like boost's.

Comment: If you must roll your own consider the `ntohl`/`ntohs`/`htons`/`htonl`/etc functions.

Comment: Also, if you want to send this file to arduino, consider using (possibly unsigned) chars wherever possible to avoid the endianness issue as well as having to deal with variables wider than the registers.

Answer (score 2):

You are simply looking at the four bytes of a 32 bit integer, interpreted on a little-endian platform.

`300 base 10 = 0x12C`

So little-endianness gives you `0x2C 0x01`, and of course `0x2C=44`.

Answer (score 2):

Each byte in the file has 8 bits, so can represent values from 0 to 255. It's written in little-endian order, with the low byte first. So, starting at the other end, treat the numbers as digits in base 256. The value is 0 * 256^3 + 0 * 256^2 + 1 * 256^1 + 44 * 256^0 (where ^ means exponentiation, not xor).

Answer (score 1):

```
    300 in binary is 100101100 which is 9 bits long.
```

But when you say char*, compiler looks for only first 1 byte(8 bits)

```
    so it is 00101100(bits) of (1 00101100) = 44
                                  ^^^^^^^^
```